# Leading tone for strings harmony

Tags: composition, harmony, strings

how to write a seventh leading tone chord for 4  part harmony for strings?.
Thank you

Comment: In what context?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many different ways.  The simplest way is to put the root in the cello, the third in the viola, the fifth in second violin, and then double the root in the first violin. You could also put the seventh (which would be the sixth note of the scale) in the first violin part.

So much depends on what is going on around the chord that it's difficult to answer the question with any degree of precision.

Comment: How does the 'seventh' become the sixth note of the scale?

Comment: @Tim, wouldn't the seventh of viio7 be LA - or LE in minor?

Comment: @Tim Imagine the key of C. vii is B. So, the root is B, the third is D, the fifth is F, and the seventh is A (this is a "half-diminished 7th" chord; a fully diminished 7th chord would use Ab). A is the sixth note of the scale in C. So, the note that is a 7th from the root is a 6th from the Tonic, if you are using the Leading Tone as the root.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. I had the wrong start point! That chord is basically V9 with no root, I think

Comment: @Tim: well, I wouldn't call it that. In classical theory, chords without roots are pretty avant-garde. I'd call it a vii half diminished chord, because that's what I was taught in school. vii half diminished 7th is an alternative to a V7 chord, both resolving to the tonic. (Now, if you're in a minor key, a ii dim7 resolves to the tonic. For example, in A minor, B-D-F-Ab is a ii dim7.  I like to use that as an alternative harmony to the V7 in blues progressions.)

Comment: In modern theory, though, (in C maj) B,D,F,A can be seen as Bm7b5 (B half-dim) , and if it is played, say, on gtr, the bass could put a G note under it - making G9. Probably not used much in Classical music, as you say.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly the way that 9th chords were thought of when they first came into vogue in the 18th century. Rameau first proposed a "supposed" bass a third below the fundamental. It didn't take long for theorists to decide that the "supposed" bass was easier to treat as the fundamental and the 9th as a transient or non-chord tone. That led to the idea of a 9th chord, although it really wasn't considered a chord in its own right until beginning of the 20th century. In the 19th century, 9th chords were typically treated as appoggiaturas, with the 9th moving down stepwise.

Comment: But this would never be without the root. I don't know of any circumstance of classical music theory that analyzes a chord without the root.

Comment: @BobRodes Piston's *Harmony* calls this chord the "incomplete dominant 9th"

Comment: @DeanRansevycz Thanks for that. I guess I could stand to brush up a bit. :)